# How to combine all functions into one column on PySpark?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Currently I am trying to combine all the functions into a column called "Gender". I have successfully done that using Pandas but now I would like to do it with PySpark and it is a bit different compare to Pandas. I am unable to call the function `.apply` in PySpark.

This is the version that I have done using Pandas:

```
df['Gender'] = df['Gender'].str.lower()

male = ["male", "m", "male-ish", "maile", "mal", "male (cis)", "make", "male ", "man", "msle", "mail", "malr","cis man", "cis male"]
female = ["cis female", "f", "female", "woman",  "femake", "female ","cis-female/femme", "female (cis)", "femail", "trans-female",  "trans woman", "female (trans)"]
other = ["non-binary", "nah", "all", "enby", "fluid", "genderqueer", "androgyne", "agender", "male leaning androgynous", "guy (-ish) ^_^", "neuter", "queer", "ostensibly male, unsure what that really means", "queer/she/they", "something kinda male?", "a little about you", "p"]

new_df['Gender'] = new_df['Gender'].apply(lambda x:"Male" if x in male else x)
new_df['Gender'] = new_df['Gender'].apply(lambda x:"Female" if x in female else x)
new_df['Gender'] = new_df['Gender'].apply(lambda x:"Other" if x in other else x)
```

This is the version that I am trying to replicate using PySpark but I am having trouble to put all the converted values back into the "Gender" column:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lower, col, udf
import pyspark.sql.functions as f 

na_df = na_df.withColumn('Gender', lower(col('Gender')))

Male = ["male", "m", "male-ish", "maile", "mal", "male (cis)", "make", "male ", "man", "msle", "mail", "malr","cis man", "cis male"]
Female = ["cis female", "f", "female", "woman",  "femake", "female ","cis-female/femme", "female (cis)", "femail", "trans-female",  "trans woman", "female (trans)"]
Other = ["non-binary", "nah", "all", "enby", "fluid", "genderqueer", "androgyne", "agender", "male leaning androgynous", "guy (-ish) ^_^", "neuter", "queer", "ostensibly male, unsure what that really means", "queer/she/they", "something kinda male?", "a little about you", "p"]

na_df2 = na_df.withColumn('Gender',f.when(f.col('Gender').isin(Male),f.lit('Male')).\
when(f.col('Gender').isin(Other),f.lit('Other')).\
when(f.col('Gender').isin(Female),f.lit('Female')).\
otherwise(f.col('Gender'))).show()

na_df2.select('Gender').distinct().show()
```

This is another version of solution that I tried but it's giving me an error of cannot convert column into bool:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lower, col, udf

na_df = na_df.withColumn('Gender', lower(col('Gender')))

genders = {
    'Male': ["male", "m", "male-ish", "maile", "mal", "male (cis)", "make", "male ", "man", "msle", "mail", "malr","cis man", "cis male"],
    'Female': ["cis female", "f", "female", "woman",  "femake", "female ","cis-female/femme", "female (cis)", "femail", "trans-female",  "trans woman", "female (trans)"],
    'Other': ["non-binary", "nah", "all", "enby", "fluid", "genderqueer", "androgyne", "agender", "male leaning androgynous", "guy (-ish) ^_^", "neuter", "queer", "ostensibly male, unsure what that really means", "queer/she/they", "something kinda male?", "a little about you", "p"]
}

na_df.withColumn('Gender', (lambda x: [g for g in genders if x in genders[g]][0])(col('Gender'))).show()
```

Result that I am getting is that, the column "Gender" hasn't been updated so please advise on what I can do to fix the problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: your pandas code has a better alternative bdw (not relevant to this question by just saying- dont use apply for such cases) take a look at how `np.select` works. With pyspark you can try withh when and oterwise as below answer says or a case when statement with selectExpr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by chaining when function

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
+---+----------+
| id|    gender|
+---+----------+
|  1|      male|
|  1|         m|
|  1|  male-ish|
|  1|     maile|
|  1|       mal|
|  1|male (cis)|
|  1|      make|
|  1|     male |
|  1|       man|
|  1|      msle|
|  1|      mail|
|  1|      malr|
|  1|   cis man|
|  1|  cis male|
|  1|cis female|
|  1|         f|
|  1|    female|
|  1|     woman|
|  1|    femake|
|  1|   female |
+---+----------+

df = df.withColumn('gender',f.when(f.col('gender').isin(male),f.lit('Male')).\
when(f.col('gender').isin(other),f.lit('Other')).\
when(f.col('gender').isin(female),f.lit('Female')).\
otherwise(f.col('gender')))


df.select('Gender').distinct().show()
+---+------+
| id|gender|
+---+------+
|  1|  Male|
|  1|  Male|
|  1|  Male|
|  1|  Male|
|  1|  Male|
|  1|  Male|
|  1|  Male|
|  1|  Male|
|  1|  Male|
|  1|  Male|
|  1|  Male|
|  1|  Male|
|  1|  Male|
|  1|  Male|
|  1|Female|
|  1|Female|
|  1|Female|
|  1|Female|
|  1|Female|
|  1|Female|
+---+------+
```

Comment: The function didn't work and I'm not sure why it didn't work. Updated my code above for review please.

Comment: what error u are getting. I hope u imported import pyspark.sql.functions as f

Comment: There's no error, just the results are still the same as nothing has happened. It didn't group them to only show "Male", "Female" and "Other". I've updated the code above for review please.

Comment: can you update the data that you have in your dataframe

Comment: What do you mean by that? I have updated my code above for review.

Comment: Updated the answer you need to assign it to a df then run distinct.

Comment: Updated the code above into a new df but it's still not giving the correct results. Would you be able to take a look at my other solution that I tried please? It's telling me that it cannot convert the column into bool.

Comment: hey please try to understand what you are doing...when you are assigning to na_df2 then don't run an action show() and in next step when you want to see the result don't assign it and run na_df2.select('Gender').distinct().show().... I hope you understand the difference between transformation and action and not just randomly doing stuff just to make it work

Comment: If I don't assign a variable then how I am suppose to the result? na_df2.select('Gender').distinct().show() return "NoneType". I've did exactly. what you. have done on your answer instead of calling it df I called it na_df2 instead and selecting the distinct values

Comment: @ Shubham Jain Nevermind solved it already thank you. It was my mistake changing the values of making the male into capital Male, female into capital Female and etc. Thank you for your help and it's been a learning journey.

Comment: For your second approach I don't think you can do this in spark i.e. creating a generator in anonymous function instead try to do it with udf.